# How to improve memory usage and performance of apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache-poi

I am trying to write 200,000 rows in Excel with around 300 columns each, using `apache-poi` for Java.

Have done couple of things like:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook(1000);
workBook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

//...populated rows

sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);  //in the end.
```

The program is taking more than 1 hour to write 200,000 * 300 data. 
How can I improve the performance without drastically increasing memory usage?

Comment: The time will decreasing drastic without using [Sheet.autoSizeColumn](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn-int-). Autosizing needs looping over all cells in a column again to determine the needed width. This repeats for each column which shall be autosized. So maybe you can set column widths to fixed values using [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-) instead?